# Create Notification

Tags: php

I wanna create notification and alert in android.I know my PHP is working but I'm a beginner of android programming. I can't write code for notification. Please help me some example. Connection may be json but I don't know exactly.

Here is my PHP.

```
class notification
{

                //database error
                sendResponse(400, "Invalid Request");
                return false;
            }
            //unicode data in database
            mysql_set_charset("utf8");
            //select data on schedule and member_status 
            $query = "     SELECT s.c_team_id";
            $query .= "          , s.dt_start_time ";
            $query .= "          , DATE_FORMAT(s.t_alert, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')as alert ";
            $query .= "          , CASE TIMEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(s.dt_start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), DATE_FORMAT(s.t_alert, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'))";

            $query .= "        AND s.t_alert >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ";
            $query .= "        AND (DATE_ADD(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)) ";
            $query.= "    ORDER BY s.t_alert";
            $query .= "      LIMIT 64 ";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            $totalRowsCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($totalRowsCount == 0)
            { 
                sendResponse(400, 'Record Not Found'); 
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
             e"] == "" ) ? "" : $row2["beforeMatchTime"]
                    );  
                    $parameter['notifications'][] = $data;
                }

    }
}
//create object
$notification = new notification;
//call method
$notification -> scheduleNotification();
?>
```

Comment: In general Android development is not done in PHP. Can you elaborate what you want to achieve and how?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want notifications from web service, better use Cloud messaging like **GCM**. Otherwise if you receive the given JSON inside android app, notifications can be set using **alarm service**.

Comment: I wanna create notification as alarm. I'll get data from database by using PHP and call into the java code by json code. I want to show notification if my app will run or not.(Please, try for me.I'm in serious.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html). Look at the info given for implementing the [client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) side, and also take a look at the following [php example](https://github.com/mozi22/GCM-Notification-Example/blob/master/GCMPushMessage.php).